# Many ESX hosts behind a router

Tags: vmware-esxi, remote-access, vmware-workstation

Two ESXi servers (**ESX1** and **ESX2**) on a LAN are connected to a router with WAN.

A port forwarding rule has been created for ports 443 and 902 and it is possible to access **ESX1**.

**ESX2** uses the same ports. Ports 444 and 903 have been chosen to redirect 443 and 902 respectively on the router, but the VMware workstation for remote console redirection is restricted to port 902.

Although it is possible to manage both hosts, only the remote consoles of **ESX1** are visible.

1. What should I do to resolve this issue?
2. Is there a way to set a second host to use an other port and VMware
   client to be aware of that?

Comment: Don't mess around with port forwarding.  Setup a VPN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way, what's wrong with doing things normally via the hosts actual ports - have you not got IP addressing freedom here? How will this scale if/as you use other products that require additional ports to the hosts?

You really need to get to a point where these are all directly-routable, anything else isn't really professional.

> Is there a way to set second host to use other port and vmware client
>   to be aware of that?

Oh and don't try this, updates will wipe any odd little work-arounds you may make anyway.

Comment: what do you mean? I want to access the servers remotely... on lan I can have whatever address I want. But I cannot rout one port (902) to many hosts.

Comment: or how to make them directly routable? I have one external ip address.

Comment: It's this last bit - the 'one external IP address' that's the problem - is this a home setup? it sounds like one - have you thought about VPN'ing into your local network?

Comment: well it's not that I can't get more external ips :) but less is better and I was trying to check some options. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Less is better" - no, nope, not often and not in this case - get those IPs or VPN

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do that?

- Create a VPN on your Router/FW
- Connect to your VPN
- Administer everything from there

I don't think you want to publish an ESX Server to the Internet.